# Why WordPress add_post_meta() function add multiple array value when the post is saved

Tags: wordpress

From the WordPress admin panel, when I press the Publish button on **Custom Post type post** page I use the following code to **save** newly created **custom post meta boxes value**:

```
public function save_listing_meta_data( $post_id ) {    
     

     if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
          return;
     }

     if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
          return;
     }

     if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) !== 'listing' ) {
          return;
     }

     // Get metaboxes value and sanitize it
     $sl_keywords    =   isset( $_POST['sl_keywords'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'sl_keywords'] ) : '';
     $sl_website     =   isset( $_POST['sl_website'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'sl_website'] ) : '';
     $sl_price       =   isset( $_POST['sl_price'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'sl_price'] ) : '';
     $sl_phone       =   isset( $_POST['sl_phone'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'sl_phone'] ) : '';
     $sl_email       =   isset( $_POST['sl_email'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'sl_email'] ) : '';
     $sl_address     =   isset( $_POST['sl_address'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'sl_address'] ) : '';
     $sl_state       =   isset( $_POST['sl_state'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'sl_state'] ) : '';
     $sl_country     =   isset( $_POST['sl_country'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'sl_country'] ) : '';
     $sl_postal      =   isset( $_POST['sl_postal'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'sl_postal'] ) : '';
     $sl_glat        =   isset( $_POST['sl_glat'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'sl_glat'] ) : '';
     $sl_glong       =   isset( $_POST['sl_glong'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'sl_glong'] ) : '';

     $sl_listing_details = [
          'sl_keywords'  =>   $sl_keywords,
          'sl_website'   =>   $sl_website, 
          'sl_price'     =>   $sl_price, 
          'sl_phone'     =>   $sl_phone, 
          'sl_email'     =>   $sl_email,
          'sl_address'   =>   $sl_address, 
          'sl_state'     =>   $sl_state,
          'sl_country'   =>   $sl_country,
          'sl_postal'    =>   $sl_postal,
          'sl_glat'      =>   $sl_glat,
          'sl_glong'     =>   $sl_glong
     ];

     add_post_meta( $post_id, 'sl_listing_details', $sl_listing_details );
}
```

**Now**, I can see that the above code is **inserting the meta boxes 2 times** instead of one time. I mean, when I use `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'sl_listing_details' )` It's showing me that array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sl_keywords] => 
            [sl_website] => 
            [sl_price] => 
            [sl_phone] => 
            [sl_email] => 
            [sl_address] => 
            [sl_state] => 
            [sl_country] => 
            [sl_postal] => 
            [sl_glat] => 
            [sl_glong] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sl_keywords] => php, mysql
            [sl_website] => www.shibbir.dev
            [sl_price] => 12.50
            [sl_phone] => +61412329684
            [sl_email] => alex@gmail.com
            [sl_address] => 
            [sl_state] => alaska
            [sl_country] => bangladesh
            [sl_postal] => 4655
            [sl_glat] => 25.52
            [sl_glong] => 26.25
        )

)
```

You can see that the `0` index. All the value of that index key is empty. When it's showing that empty key value paid.

It's should show me only 1 multiple dimensional arrays, right?